# How to make a request to a web page with PHP?

Tags: php, browser

What i'm trying to achieve is this:

1st- I want to query a page like google but without filling it's search filed manually
2nd- I want to get the result and save it to a database

I saw an example of doing this with C# here

http://www.farooqazam.net/c-sharp-auto-click-button-and-auto-fill-form/comment-page-1/#comment-27256

but i'd like to do it with php, can you help me please?

Thanks

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I have nothing, i'm still searching

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to do so, not only because it is [way faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555523/file-get-contents-vs-curl-what-has-better-performance) than file_get_contents, but also because it has many more features. Another reason to use it is that, as Xeoncross correctly mentioned in the comments, file_get_contents may be disabled by your webhost for security reasons.

A basic example would be this one:

```
$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com' );
curl_exec( $curl_handle ); // Execute the request
curl_close( $curl_handle );
```

If you need the return data from the request, you need to specify the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option:

```
$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com' );
curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true ); // Fetch the contents too
$html = curl_exec( $curl_handle ); // Execute the request
curl_close( $curl_handle );
```

There are tons of cURL options, for example, you can set a request timeout:

```
curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2 ); // 2 second timeout
```

For a reference of all options see the [curl_setopt()](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.curl-setopt.php) reference.

Comment: Can you give an example please?

Comment: This is the recommended approach. Also, some hosts disable `file_get_contents()` http protocal because it's not build for this type of thing as well.

Comment: You can even pass cookies, headers, or handle redirects.

Answer (score 3):

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://example.com');
```

is the simplest version you'll get.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$r = new HttpRequest('http://example.com/feed.rss', HttpRequest::METH_GET);
$r->setOptions(array('lastmodified' => filemtime('local.rss')));
$r->addQueryData(array('category' => 3));
try {
    $r->send();
    if ($r->getResponseCode() == 200) {
        file_put_contents('local.rss', $r->getResponseBody());
    }
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
    echo $ex;
}
?>
```

From the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.httprequest-send.php)...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHP CUrl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), for detailed manupulations with the site you access!

you can even perform get and posts on the site you access, or use services from different sites (in case the site provides services!).

Answer (score 0):

If you find the name of the field (q) you want to fill on the remote page (Google), you can fill it by using GET syntax:

```
http://www.google.com/?q=hello
```

Comment: @x3ro It has to do with the C# link that he posted.  The OP seems to be asking two different questions.  The first question was how to query Google without typing in the search box.

Comment: Ah, my bad, sorry. I thought he had figured that out already, and was now asking for a way to do this programatically. Had to edit the answer to remove the downvote ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help, the C# example was quite easy because i'm used to work with c# but i'm kind of a newbie on PHP so i'll give it a try.