# obsfuscate a request url inside javascript using Laravel/Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

I'm not sure if this is a great idea or can be accomplished, but I really need to do this. So, I'm trying to obsfuscate an URL that has to be used in a Javascript as a parameter. Something like this :

```
<script>
 myFunction({
  id : 'my-id',
  url : 'http://www.my-open-url.com'
 });
</script>
```

Now, what I want to do is, use something other than this open url in this way :

```
<script>
 myFunction({
  id : 'my-id',
  url : 'http://myapp.com/url/encrypted'
 });
</script>
```

So I already have a Controller and a method ready that can return the expected url if that encrypted url is hit :

```
Route::get('url/encrypted' array('uses'=>'UrlController@returnUrl'));
```

The returnUrl method can be something like this

```
public function returnUrl(){

    //Some algorithm to obtain the original url from database goes here

    return 'http://www.my-open-url.com'; //the actual url is returned to the script

}
```

To put it simply, I don't want users to "view source" and see the real remote URL I'm using to obtain something from other site.

So, is it possible to use some sort of Ajax call inside that script to obtain the url from that controller real-time ?

I'm not sure if I could make myself clear. Any advices and edits and moderation are most welcome :)

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: you can obfuscate the code, but it will still be there for anyone to see. Why do you need to hide it?

Comment: There's no point in doing this. There's no difference between requesting `http://example.com/path` over `http://example.com/abc123`. All you're doing is introducing a few more round-trips to the server that won't prevent bots, nor humans, to reach the target URL.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I understand Andre and Ben. But this really is a special case :) You know, every problem is unique. If it wasn't necessary, I wouldn't have asked.

But I do understand the Logic behind the point you made. (y) For that :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is impossible. Someone can correct me if I'm wrong.

But what is your purpose of obfuscating the URL? I can suggest some other ways to accomplish your task.

When you right click and view source, what you are seeing is the original "text" of the document before any javascript that alters the structure is ran.

When the page is loading or after the page has loaded, you can inspect element to see the final results of the document after it has been modified using javascript.

If you are going to send the decrypted URL back to the client, they can just see the network traffic and inspect its contents using Google Chrome.

[image]

Comment: Yes you can. You make a call for the "encrypted" URL and within the response you make the second call with the real URL. However, it is useless.

Comment: Hi Ben, can you please elaborate? Sorry if I'm asking for too much. I really didn't get the idea of what you suggested.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input @AmuletxHeart . It was informative.

Comment: Okay, to be honest, I'm even ready to compromise Application performance for this bit of encryption/security.

Say, I want to stream something from a secret server and I don't want other people to see it. Cause it's very much possible for them to grab the URL and do things with it. Even provide the same service I'm providing -- illegally --.

IP restricting is not option here by the way.

Comment: NVM :) I think I got a solution on my own

Comment: I think what @tintinboss was saying is that when you request http://myapp.com/url/encrypted, instead of returning a string of the decrypted URL, the server request http://www.my-open-url.com on behalf on the client instead. The server is acting like a client and once it has loaded the full HTML page, the server replies to the original client with a HTML page instead of just a string. See this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984103/how-to-make-a-request-to-a-web-page-with-php

Comment: Also, set up HTTPS/TLS on your server and force all traffic to be redirected to HTTPS only. I think that is a much bigger security loophole compared to this problem.