# How ill I grab content of any div on a specific website and display it's contents

Tags: php, python-3.x, web-services

I feel this is easier than I think, but where do I start.

About me: I know my way around frontend dev, had exposure to php as well as advanced beginner knowledge of python.

I want to write a script that goes like this:

go to website
for each div class xyz
          open href 
          grab certain content from newly opened document
          add selected content to dictionary

output dictionary as html file

Comment: rtfm: http request with [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) , [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) or [XML Parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php), see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984103/how-to-make-a-request-to-a-web-page-with-php

Comment: This is a very broad question. You should play around with the information on the given links and come back with a more specific question.

Comment: What you are trying to do is called web scrapping and python has some very good libraries to do the job.